# Wrong items in section when fetching from To - Many Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following relationship:

[image]

I now want to fetch all the SubMenuGroups for a Product and then all the Submenus for the groups.

This is what I currently have:

```
+ (NSFetchRequest *)getSubMenusForProduct:(Product *)product {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =  [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[self entityName]];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group.product.remoteID == %@ && group.product == %@", product.remoteID, product];


    NSSortDescriptor *groupSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"group.name"
                                                                        ascending:YES];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortVal"
                                                                   ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[groupSortDescriptor, sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    return fetchRequest;
}
```

This fetches the groups fine, execpt that sometimes the subMenus is sectioned under the wrong groups (when the data is updated). How would I manage to fetch all the subMenuGroups for a product and then section the subMenus under the right groups?

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate format string includes the self (`group`). It should just be `product`, not `group.product`. The same applies to your sort descriptor.

This assumes that the cryptic `[self entityName]` is indeed `@"SubMenuGroup"`.
If, however, it is `@"SubMenus"`, your predicate is redundant. The following would be enough:

```
@"product = %@", product
```

The problem is thus in the update. Maybe you should examine your fetched results controller and fetched results controller delegate code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am trying to fetch is the SubMenus ([self entityName] = SubMenus), grouped under there groups. Should I still change by predicate and sortDescriptors then?

Comment: Ah, in this case your predicate is almost OK (I will edit my answer), at least it should work. Your problem is the update - this is independent from the retch request.